# valid and invalid mapping

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$ Map(\{5,2,3,0,6,3,9\},\{6,3,1,2,4\}) \neq \{(0,4),(5,3),(3,6),(6,4),(9,6),(2,3),(3,3) \}$$

Why is the map not valid? My first guess was that it is not valid because no value is mapped to 1,2. But then the second map should be invalid which it is not.

$$ Map(\{ 3,8,1,9,5,7,4\}, \{7,8,0,3,2\}) = \{ (5,0),(3,8),(7,7),(8,0),(1,8),(9,2),(4,8) \}$$

For this map no value is mapped to 3,2 and it is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A map takes each element to exactly one element (image). In the first one $3$ is getting mapped to two different images.

For a relation to be a map, it is not required that all elements of the co-domain be used.

Comment: @jublikon surjectivity is an additional condition that can be imposed on a map. So if a given map has to be surjective, then it will require the entire co-domain to be used.